# d3 multi line chart with zoom and update

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to add a zoom to my d3 line-chart and got a problem with the domain. It seems like the domain for the second line isn't updated, it just uses the domain values from the first line and therefore the second line isn't visible (the values in the csv are much bigger).
The goal is that both lines fit to the canvas, no matter how bid the data is. All of the graphs should be scaled to 100% height of the canvas.

Please let me know if you have any idea what I have to change.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<style>
rect.pane {
  cursor: move;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
} 
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 1;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #26b2d5;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.line2 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #bdc1cc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
</style>

      <!--NAVIGATION-->
      <nav>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'>First</a>
                    <li><a href='#'><div>
                            <input type="button" 
                                   value="A" 
                                   onclick="updateFirst();updateA();" />
                    </div></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'><div>
                            <input type="button" 
                                   value="B" 
                                   onclick="updateFirst();updateB();" />
                    </div></a></li>
                  </li>            

                <li><a href='#'>Second</a>
                    <li><a href='#'><div>
                            <input type="button" 
                                   value="A" 
                                   onclick="updateSecond();updateA();" />
                    </div></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'><div>
                            <input type="button" 
                                   value="B" 
                                   onclick="updateSecond();updateB();" />
                    </div></a></li>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </nav>

      <!--MAIN-->
      <main>

      <script>
        var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
            width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 570 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%W-%Y").parse,
            formatDate = d3.time.format("%Y");

        var x = d3.time.scale()
            .range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .ticks(15)
            .tickPadding(6);
        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left")
            .ticks(5)
            .tickPadding(6);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.meldewoche); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.faelle); });
        var line2 = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.woche); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.anzahl); });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); 

        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .on("zoom", draw);

        svg.append("clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
          .append("rect")
            .attr("x", x(0))
            .attr("y", y(1))
            .attr("width", x(1) - x(0))
            .attr("height", y(0) - y(1));

        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis");

        svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

        svg.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "pane")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(zoom);


        d3.csv("data-a.csv", function(error, data) {
              if (error) throw error;

                data.forEach(function(d) {
                    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m-%Y").parse
                    d.woche = parseDate(d.woche);
                    d.anzahl = +d.anzahl;
           });
            x.domain([new Date(2001, 01), new Date(2015, 12)]);
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.anzahl; })]);
            zoom.x(x); 

            svg.append("path")
                .attr("class", "line2")
                .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

            svg.select("path.line2").data([data]);

            function test() {
              svg.select("g.x.axis").call(xAxis);
              svg.select("g.y.axis").call(yAxis);
              svg.select("path.line2").attr("d", line2);
            }
        });

        d3.csv("data-first.csv", function(error, data) {
              if (error) throw error;

                data.forEach(function(d) {
                    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%W-%Y").parse;
                    d.meldewoche = parseDate(d.meldewoche);
                    d.faelle = +d.faelle;
            });
            x.domain([new Date(2001, 01), new Date(2016, 01)]);
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.faelle; })]);
            zoom.x(x);

            svg.select("path.line").data([data]);
              draw();
        });

        function updateFirst() {              
        d3.csv("data-first.csv", function(error, data) {
              if (error) throw error;

                data.forEach(function(d) {
                    parseDate = d3.time.format("%W-%Y").parse
                    d.meldewoche = parseDate(d.meldewoche);
                    d.faelle = +d.faelle;
            });
            x.domain([new Date(2001, 01), new Date(2016, 01)]);
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.faelle; })]);
            zoom.x(x);

            svg.selectAll("path.line").data([data]);
            update();
        });
        }

        function updateSecond() {              
        d3.csv("data-second.csv", function(error, data) {
              if (error) throw error;

                data.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.meldewoche = parseDate(d.meldewoche);
                    d.faelle = +d.faelle;
            });
            x.domain([new Date(2001, 01), new Date(2015, 01)]);
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.faelle; })]);
            zoom.x(x);

            svg.selectAll("path.line").data([data]);
            update();
        });
        }

        function updateA() {              
        d3.csv("data-a.csv", function(error, data) {
              if (error) throw error;

                data.forEach(function(d) {
                var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m-%Y").parse;
                    d.woche = parseDate(d.woche);
                    d.anzahl = +d.anzahl;
            });

            x.domain([new Date(2001, 01), new Date(2015, 01)]);
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.anzahl; })]);
            zoom.x(x);

            svg.selectAll("path.line2").data([data]);
            update();
        });
        }

        function updateB() {              
        d3.csv("data-b.csv", function(error, data) {
              if (error) throw error;

                data.forEach(function(d) {
                var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m-%Y").parse;
                    d.woche = parseDate(d.woche);
                    d.anzahl = +d.anzahl;
            });

            x.domain([new Date(2001, 01), new Date(2015, 01)]);
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.anzahl+50; })]);
            zoom.x(x);

            svg.selectAll("path.line2").data([data]);
            update();
        });
        }

        function update() {
          svg.select("g.x.axis").transition().duration(350).call(xAxis);
          svg.select("g.y.axis").transition().duration(350).call(yAxis);
          svg.selectAll("path.line").transition().duration(750).attr("d", line);
          svg.selectAll("path.line2").transition().duration(750).attr("d", line2);
        }

        function draw() {
          svg.select("g.x.axis").call(xAxis);
          svg.select("g.y.axis").call(yAxis);
          svg.select("path.line").attr("d", line);
          svg.select("path.line2").attr("d", line2);
        }     
    </script>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to also provide all the csv's for us to try out.

Comment: Your code only sets domain for the last file loaded.  Any time you modify the domain, look at the current one and min/max it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set your domains in your update functions, you only look at the current file.  You should be comparing the current domain to the one currently in use and see if you need to set a new max.

Here's what you have:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.anzahl+50; })]);
```

Here's what you need:

```
var newMax = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.anzahl+50; });
var oldMax = y.domain()[1];

if (newMax > oldMax){
  y.domain([0, newMax]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It wasn't exactly what I wanted, I need two different domains for the two lines, but I added a second y variable and it works!